# Not able to scroll nested listview

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-listview

The nested listview is not scrolling properly, when I scroll it rolls back to the top position by itself, does not retain the actual position

```
Container(
  width:screenSize.width,
  child: ListView(

    scrollDirection:Axis.vertical,
    children: <Widget>[new Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 20,10, 0),
      // color: Colors.red,
      width: screenSize.width,
  height: screenSize.height,
      child:  Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[

            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
              Text('Text1'),
              Text('Text1'),
            ],),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
              Text('Text1'),
              Text('Text1'),
            ],),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
              Text('Text1'),
              Text('Text1'),
            ],),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
              Text('Text1'),
              Text('Text1'),
            ],),
            Row
              (
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
              Text('Text1'),
              Text('Text1'),
            ],),
          ],),
          // ListView()
          SizedBox(height: 25,),
           SizedBox(
             width: 300,
            child: new ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[

            Container(

            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[

                Text('Item Details' + "1/2"),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Text1'),
                    Text('Text1'),
                  ],),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Text1'),
                    Text('Text1'),
                  ],),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Text1'),
                    Text('Text1'),
                  ],),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Text1'),
                    Text('Text1'),
                  ],),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Text1'),
                    Text('Text1'),
                  ],),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Text1'),
                    Text('Text1'),
                  ],),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Text1'),
                    Text('Text1'),
                  ],),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Text1'),
                    Text('Text1'),
                  ],),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Text1'),
                    Text('Text1'),
                  ],),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Text1'),
                    Text('Text1'),
                  ],),
                RaisedButton(

                  color: Colors.greenAccent,  onPressed: () {


                  Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Approved Item");
                },
                  child:  Text("APPROVE"),

                )


              ],
            ),
           )


              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),],
  ),
),
```

I tried to identify where the problem is but could not get it as of now, various things experimented but failed to understand when we scroll the nested listview, why it is hinged to the top position and does not retain or show the new scrolled context.

Please advise the solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify scroll physics ( that is what handles the scroll behavior of a `ListView`) for each `ListView`s if you're using nested `ListView`s.

By default a `ListView` has `ClampingScrollPhysics` on Android and `BouncingScrollPhysics` on ios platform. That means on android platform the scrolling clamps on the boundaries of `ListView` and on ios it the `ListView` bounces up and down.
So, If we use nested `ListView`s the parent list clamps on it's limits. It may not know what kind of widget are it's children. To avoid this problem we need to create a `ListView` that always scrolls, for that we have to use `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics`.

Here is the fixed version of your sample code.

```
ListView(
    physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    children: <Widget>[
      new Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 20, 10, 0),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Text1'),
                    Text('Text1'),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            // ListView()
            SizedBox(
              height: 25,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 300,
              child: new ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 100,
                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (context, int index) => RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.greenAccent,
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text("APPROVE $index"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

And here is a working [demo](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/16466dbc90298f6a50284a4c8215b6ee)

Comment: I did as you recommended, but still the same issue persists

Comment: what platform? web, desktop or on mobile?

Comment: I am using ios simulator but please make sure it is also working on android as well

Comment: Resolved the issue, it was because of the height constraint in a parent container